# Yahoo China account will shut down soon. How can I change it?

Tags: support, login, openid, yahoo

I am using China YahooID as my Stack Overflow OpenID. Unfortunately, China Yahoo email service will be shut down in August.

What should I do? Alternatively, could I bind current account with other OpenID? For example, to bind to a Google account?

Comment: Create a gmail account and add it into your profile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change your OpenID. Just go to your profile -> click *my logins* -> click *add more logins...*. You can also remove your old login (i.e. YahooID).

> [image]

Comment: What can I say? It works! Thank you @hims056 !