# Porting Google OpenID to Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid

I've been using Google Openid for sometime to login to Stack Exchange network.
Lately I started to work with another Google account on my PC.
this causes Stack Exchange to try to login with the wrong Google account.
I decided that I rather use Stack Exchange Openid to login instead.

Is there a way to port my Gmail openID user to Stack Exchange openID user?

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182463/