# Is there a way to protect my Stack Overflow account as my Gmail account was hacked and I am using it for my account?

Tags: support, hacked

Is there a way to protect my Stack Overflow account as my [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) account was hacked and I am using it for Stack Overflow login?

The hacker can easily enter to my Stack Overflow account. Is there a way to restrict it?

Comment: You can add other logins and remove your hacked gmail account. Go to your profile page and click the "my logins" link to manage your logins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/187824). Or [Yahoo China account will shut down soon. How can I change it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182463/187824)

Comment: Someone hacks into your Gmail account and you're worried about Stack Overflow? (I hope it's a throwaway account)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your profile page there is a "my logins" link that clicking on will produce a popup that lets you manage your logins:

[image: logins]

You can add a new login and delete the compromised account.